# NameError: name 'countryCodeMap' is not defined

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am trying to implement a Spark program in a Databricks Cluster and I am following the documentation whose link is as follows:

Now, after this line of code:

```
def mapKeyToVal(mapping):
  def mapKeyToVal_(col):
    return mapping.get(col)
  return udf(mapKeyToVal_, StringType())
```

I am using this:

```
gameInfDf = gameInfDf.withColumn("country_code", mapKeyToVal(countryCodeMap)("country"))
```

And I am getting the Error: **name 'countryCodeMap' is not defined**

It will be great if anyone can help me with the same.

Comment: Did you follow all the steps?

Comment: Yes, I followed all the above steps !

Comment: I see no map defined there

Comment: It's not present in the document and I was wondering the same thing .

Comment: they have missed a few things

Comment: Could you possibly help what should I add ?

Comment: need to create  a Map or number of them. may be there is a way of loading these

Comment: pls see answer, not that hard

Comment: Yes, I am looking into it

Comment: quite easy, just down load, unzip import the .dbc and have a good look around. it's all there. bob's your uncle as they say in Australia...

Comment: Haha! Thank you very much

I have imported the .dbc file and it is showing an issue:

TypeError: udf() takes from 0 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: Yes Sir, No problem.

Done the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://databricks.com/blog/2018/07/09/analyze-games-from-european-soccer-leagues-with-apache-spark-and-databricks.html  is the formal guide for databricks.

See picture below. You need to click on the link and IMPORT the .dbc

[image]

You will then see various setupo things. E.g. the Maps needed. Good stuff.

You can see the maps, some of them:

```
situationMap = {1:'Open play', 2:'Set piece', 3:'Corner', 4:'Free kick', 99:'NA'}

countryCodeMap = {'germany':'DEU', 'france':'FRA', 'england':'GBR', 'spain':'ESP', 'italy':'ITA'}
```